# How to set the unique property for Schema by using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose in NodeJS to operate MongoDB database. One problem I have is that when I define a Schema, I want to set a field in that Schema to be unique. I set the field according to [the instructions of the official document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options), but it didn't work. Some people know that when defining Schema, how to define a field value is unique? The Mongoose version I used is V5.2.13.

Answer (score 3):

you just have to add `unique: true`
e.g:

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
    test: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. But it didn't work. Note that, the mongoose version I used is V5.2.13. I have see your answer on Github.